# FosElasticaBundle populate with serializer don't index all fields

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I'm working with FOS Elastica bundle and trying to index some datas inside Elasticsearch.

I followed the doc so I wrote this conf

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_HOST)%', port: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_PORT)%' }
    indexes:
        app:
            index_name: app
            types:
                user:
                    serializer:
                        groups: [elastica]
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: AppBundle\Entity\User
                        provider: ~
                country:
                    serializer:
                        groups: [elastica]
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: AppBundle\Entity\Country
                        provider: ~
```

Then inside my entities I added the serialization group

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
...

/**
 * @ORM\Table
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Country
{
    ...

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Groups({"elastica"})
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(max=64)
     */
    private $name = '';
}
```

Then when I launch `fos:elastica:populate` everything is working well but all the field where I put the `elastica` serialization group are not indexed.

I'm using the Symfony serializer and folloewed the official docs but I don't understand and find why I fields are not indexed.

I tried to add

```
serializer:
    serializer: serializer
```

or

```
serializer: ~
```

But I get an error

> Malformed action/metadata line [3], expected START_OBJECT but found [VALUE_STRING]

When I try without the serializer, everything is working well and all the defined field are indexed.

Did someone know how to fix this error ? Every issues I found on the FosElastica GitHub repo are related to the JMSSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your [exclusion strategy](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies) is not set to "all". If that is the case, ou should use @JMS\Expose() in order to expose the field to the given groups.

For example :

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;


 /**
  * @JMS\Expose()
  * @JMS\Groups(["elastica"})
  */
 private $name = '';
```